# How to change styles in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a file (non-React component, it is just a JS file) with constants with colors in the project and in the same file a variable (nightTheme) and a function (nightThemeSwitch).

```
export let nightTheme = false;

export const nightThemeSwitch = () => {
  nightTheme = !nightTheme;
};

export const WHITE = nightTheme ? '# 315e7e' : '#ffffff';
export const NAVY_BLUE = nightTheme ? '# 4d80a5' : '# 000099';
export const ABOUT_TEXT = nightTheme ? '# A4B7CB' : '# 27587B';

etc.......
```

In the main index.js file React Native, I import the function (nightThemeSwitch). I call it through the React Context and change the state, but the styles don't change, only the transparency changes (transparency I think so).

The localStorage does not help me, because the first render React does not see it. ReloadBundle doesn't help me. ForceUpdate doesn't help me either.

Is there a problem with the React.memo? Perhaps you have an idea how to solve this problem? Please tell me. Thanks in advance!

Code:

Main React Component **index.js**

```
this.state.nightThemeFunction = () => {
  nightThemeSwitch();

  this.setState(() => ({
    nightThemeContext: nightTheme,
  }));

  // localStorage.setItem('nightTheme', JSON.stringify(!nightTheme));
  // this.forceUpdate();
  // reloadBundle();
};
```

React Component **Settings.js**

```
<Switch
  onValueChange={() => {
    this.context.nightThemeFunction();
  }}
  value={nightTheme}
  trackColor={{ true: ORANGE }}
  thumbColor={COMMON_WHITE}
/>
```

I have attached a photo. You can see that at the first render, the localStorage is not visible, so it does not work.

[image]

Comment: I guess you're trying to make a light/dark theme switch logic. You need to share the code which you're trying to do that. We cannot help you without how you try to do that.

Comment: @FreakyCoder thanks for the answer. I have added additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to learn more about React, your code seems weird.
You can do it that way

index.js

```
componenDidMount(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('theme').then((theme) => this.setState({theme}))
}

switchTheme(){
    const theme = this.state.theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
    this.setState({theme})
    AsyncStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
}

render(){
    return(
        <Settings switchTheme={() => this.switchTheme()} theme={this.state.theme} />
    )
}
```

Settings.js

```
<Switch
  onValueChange={() => this.props.switchTheme()}
  value={this.props.theme}
  trackColor={{ this.props.theme === dark ? 'black' : 'white'}}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This is not what I need, but thanks!